# Import Facebook SDK for Ads Manager

Tags: swift, xcode, facebook, uikit, facebook-sdk-4.0

I need to use Facebook Ads Manager to advertise my application, for this I need to have Facebook SDK in the application.

So what I have done for this:

I imported the Facebook SDK into the project via Add Package Dependencies. I imported FacebookCore into AppDelagate.
And filled out the info.plist as instructed with all the id's and client token.
And sent the application for release, and now it says in Facebook Developers that SDK is not detected.

The strange thing is that during testing on ios simulator Facebook was able to see a new event, namely the installation of the application, and now it supposedly does not see the SDK, and does not see that the new version of the application is already published.

Who knows how to solve this?